# В массиве X = (x1, x2, ..., xn) поменять местами первый и второй отрицательные элементы, третий и четвертый отрицательные элементы и т.д

Tags: c++

Файл **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.cpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Ukrainian");

DynamicMasive X;

int N = 0;

std::cout << "Кількість елементів масива Х = ";
std::cin >> N;

srand(time(0));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    X.InsertValue(1+rand()%41-20); 
}

X.DisplayData();


}
```

Файл **сlass.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.hpp"

//Конструктор за замовчуванням
DynamicMasive :: DynamicMasive()
{
    Data = NULL;
    Length = 0;
}

//Конструктор 
DynamicMasive :: DynamicMasive(int Size)
{
    Data = (int* )malloc(Size*sizeof(int)); //Data = new int[Size]
    Length = Size;
}

//Деструктор
DynamicMasive :: ~DynamicMasive()
{
    if (Data!=NULL)
        free(Data);  
}

//Процедура для введення елементів масиву
void DynamicMasive :: InsertValue(int Value)
{
    Length++;
    Data = (int*)realloc(Data,Length*sizeof(int));
    Data[Length - 1] = Value;
}

//Процедура, що повертає значення елемента масиву за індексом
int DynamicMasive :: GetValue(int i)
{
    return(Data[i]);
}

//Процедура, що відображає масив
void DynamicMasive :: DisplayData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i <<") " << Data[i] << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

Файл *-class.hpp

```
    class DynamicMasive
{
    private:
        int * Data;
        int Length;
    public:
        DynamicMasive(); //Конструктор за замовчуванням 
        DynamicMasive(int Size); //Конструктор
        ~DynamicMasive(); //Деструктор
        int GetValue(int i); //Метод, що повертає значення елемента масиву за індексом.

        void InsertValue(int Value); //Процедура для ведення елементів масиву
        void DisplayData(); //Процедура що відображає масив
};
```

Я создал генерацию массива и вывод его на экран, и что то не могу понять как найти и поменять местами его отрицательные элементы. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно завести массив neg на 4 элемента для хранения индексов отрицательных элементов и счётчик cnt

Обходите массив в цикле for. Если встретили отрицательный элемент - записываете текущий индекс в neg[cnt] и увеличиваете cnt. Когда дошли дол четвёртого отрицательного - останавливает цикл и выполняете swap элементов с соответствующими индексами из массива.